# Gunicorn workers keep on getting terminated with signal 4 when trying to deploy with Kubernetes

Tags: flask, kubernetes, gunicorn

I have created a gunicorn server and trying to deploy it with Kubernetes, but the workers keeps on getting terminated due to signal 4.

```
[2021-12-22 05:32:21 +0000] [6] [WARNING] Worker with pid 22711 was terminated due to signal 4
[2021-12-22 05:32:21 +0000] [22736] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22736
[2021-12-22 05:32:23 +0000] [6] [WARNING] Worker with pid 22736 was terminated due to signal 4
[2021-12-22 05:32:23 +0000] [22761] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22761
[2021-12-22 05:32:24 +0000] [6] [WARNING] Worker with pid 22761 was terminated due to signal 4
[2021-12-22 05:32:24 +0000] [22786] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22786
[2021-12-22 05:32:26 +0000] [6] [WARNING] Worker with pid 22786 was terminated due to signal 4
[2021-12-22 05:32:26 +0000] [22811] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22811
[2021-12-22 05:32:28 +0000] [6] [WARNING] Worker with pid 22811 was terminated due to signal 4
[2021-12-22 05:32:28 +0000] [22836] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22836
[2021-12-22 05:32:30 +0000] [6] [WARNING] Worker with pid 22836 was terminated due to signal 4
[2021-12-22 05:32:30 +0000] [22861] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22861
[2021-12-22 05:32:32 +0000] [6] [WARNING] Worker with pid 22861 was terminated due to signal 4
[2021-12-22 05:32:32 +0000] [22886] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22886
[2021-12-22 05:32:33 +0000] [6] [WARNING] Worker with pid 22886 was terminated due to signal 4
[2021-12-22 05:32:33 +0000] [22911] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22911
[2021-12-22 05:32:35 +0000] [6] [WARNING] Worker with pid 22911 was terminated due to signal 4
[2021-12-22 05:32:35 +0000] [22936] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22936
[2021-12-22 05:32:37 +0000] [6] [WARNING] Worker with pid 22936 was terminated due to signal 4
[2021-12-22 05:32:37 +0000] [22961] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22961
[2021-12-22 05:32:39 +0000] [6] [WARNING] Worker with pid 22961 was terminated due to signal 4
```

Comment: Can you run the container image locally? Signal 4 corresponds to an illegal instruction. Is it possible that your container is built for ARM and you're running on Kubernetes on x86 (nodes) or vice versa?

Comment: Docker container on the same hosts works fine.

Comment: Also, workers stopped crashing if I set rhe request memory limit to 20Gi in the deployment file. I don't know why this works.